# Unable to open "/var/run/tor/tor0.pid" for writing: Permission denied after multiple instances

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tor

I am working on a tor server which need to load two instances (one hidden service and one relay). 
When i'am using one instances it's working fine... but with [this tutorial](https://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/server#multiple_tor_processes) I have a permission problem on the pid

With the original daemon it's working fine i'havent any problem of permission...

But if i use [this one](https://gist.github.com/7adietri/9122199) which add this :

```
# --- Multi-instance init ---

config="/etc/tor"
arrrgs="$ARGS"
command=$1
shift
instances=$*

instances() {
    case $instances in
        "")
            for c in $config/*.cfg
            do
                base=${c##*/}
                test -f "$c" && echo ${base%.cfg}
            done
            ;;
        *)
            echo "$instances"
            ;;
    esac
}

case "$command" in
    start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status)
        highest=0
        for i in $(instances)
        do
            NAME=$i
            DESC=$i
            TORPID="$TORPIDDIR/$i.pid"
            ARGS="$arrrgs -f $config/$i.cfg"
            execute $command
            status=$?
            test $status -gt $highest && highest=$status
        done
        exit $highest
        ;;
    *)
        execute
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

I have the error in the notice0/1.log

*Sep 29 16:47:10.000 [warn] Unable to open "/var/run/tor/tor0.pid" for writing: Permission denied*

So I-can't stop the instance of tor... How is-it possible ? How to correct-it ? What is the difference regarding permission between the first daemon (the original one) and the new one...

Thanks a lot by advance

EDIT :

If in config I have  **PidFile /var/run/tor/tor.pid** it's working no permission problem but if I have **PidFile /var/run/tor/tor0.pid** permission error... What the ??

Comment: The permission of /var/run/tor is : drwx--S---  2 debian-tor debian-tor   80 Sep 29 17:24 tor

Comment: What user owns each of the PID files?  Maybe tor0.pid got owned by root or some other user?  To stop it manually just run `kill -3 xxx` as root where xxx is the PID of the Tor process you want to stop.  Then as root delete the PID file it didn't have permission to write to.

Comment: There isn't tor0.pid file in the directory :(. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just move all the pid file to **/var/lib/tor/tor*.pid** and it's now working...

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/tor
NAME=tor
DESC="tor daemon"
TORLOGDIR=/var/log/tor
TORPIDDIR=/var/lib/tor
TORPID=$TORPIDDIR/tor.pid
DEFAULTSFILE=/etc/default/$NAME
```

And modify in the config

```
## The directory for keeping all the keys/etc. By default, we store
## things in $HOME/.tor on Unix, and in Application Data\tor on Windows. DataDirectory /var/lib/tor/0 
PidFile /var/lib/tor/tor0.pid
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices0.log
```

If someone know why it's working now it will be great.

Thanks